# Unit Testing Azure Function with Change Feed Trigger

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write a unit test for an Azure Function with Change Feed Trigger.

Is it possible to trigger the function using document db emulator?

or

Should I call onto the function directly?

e.g., FunctionClass.Run(documents, null);

Also, is there any example on creating unit test for azure function?

I wasn't able to find any examples for similar cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing means testing code in isolation, without dependencies on things like DB emulators.

So yes, just use your unit testing framework of choice and call `Run` directly, mocking any internal dependencies if needed.

You can find a couple examples [in this repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-unittesting-sample/tree/master/DotNet/DotNet.Test).